# in what order mongoose Model.updateMany() excutes the passed parameters?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

in my project, I was trying to update a field's value with another field's before setting the latter to 0, so logically you will set

```
second_filed = first_filed;
first_filed = 0;
```

because it's meaningless if you did the other way around. but in updateMany() it does the other way around.

here's the code I was trying to achieve, it set both values to 0:

```
await Product.updateMany({}, 
      [
        { $set: {
          "ratingsQuantityLastMonth": "$ratingsQuantityThisMonth",
            }
        }
      ],
      {
        ratingsQuantityThisMonth: 0
      }
    );
```

but what works perfectly with me is this:

```
await Product.updateMany({},
      {
        ratingsQuantityThisMonth: 0
      },
      [
        { $set: {
          "ratingsQuantityLastMonth": "$ratingsQuantityThisMonth",
            }
        }
      ]
    );
```

I really don't understand why. Could anyone explain how updateMany() is behave ?

Comment: the third parameter is an options [according to mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.updateMany()) so you need both the updates in the second param something like https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ij11ewiE86i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mongoose [`Model.updateMany()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.updateMany()) operates almost exactly like the MongoDB native [`db.collection.updateMany()`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) in that they both take 3 parameters.

These are `(filter, update, options)` with some additional options available in the mongoose `options` object.

When you ran this code:

```js
await Product.updateMany({}, 
      [
        { $set: {
          "ratingsQuantityLastMonth": "$ratingsQuantityThisMonth",
            }
        }
      ],
      {
        ratingsQuantityThisMonth: 0
      }
    );
```

The second parameter you passed in was an aggregation stage `[]` which will be applied to all documents because your first parmeter was an empty object `{}` so it matches all documents. Your third parameter was ignored because `ratingsQuantityThisMonth` is not a valid option. So the only thing that would have changed would be you set `ratingsQuantityLastMonth` = `ratingsQuantityThisMonth`. The `ratingsQuantityThisMonth` would be unaffected.

Then you when you this code:

```js
await Product.updateMany({},
      {
        ratingsQuantityThisMonth: 0
      },
      [
        { $set: {
          "ratingsQuantityLastMonth": "$ratingsQuantityThisMonth",
            }
        }
      ]
    );
```

You set all `ratingsQuantityThisMonth` = `0` because this was the second parameter. Your third parameter was an array so it was ignored because it's not a valid options object.

Between both pieces of code you inadvertently achieved the desired outcome. There was no unusual behaviour in the database.

This would have been the **correct code to use**:

```js
const update = await Product.updateMany({},
    [
        {
            $set: {
                ratingsQuantityLastMonth: "$ratingsQuantityThisMonth",
            }
        },
        {
            $set: {
                ratingsQuantityThisMonth: 0,
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

The first parameter is the `filter`, an empty object. The second parameter is an aggregation stage consisting of 2 `$set` stages. Firstly, set `ratingsQuantityLastMonth` = `ratingsQuantityThisMonth`. Then secondly set `ratingsQuantityThisMonth` = `0`.

Since the code returns an update status object you can check the value of the variable `update` to see if the update was successful or not. It will look something like this, note the `modifiedCount` which is really important:

```js
{
   "acknowledged": true,
   "modifiedCount": 125,
   "upsertedId": null,
   "upsertedCount": 0,
   "matchedCount": 125
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR THE COMPREHENSIVE EXPLANATION, I thought the second piece of code was working but when I tried it again after seeing your answer it appeared not

Comment: @Marya you're welcome. Hopefully your question helps someone else in the future.